# magento free shipping and keep shipping price for report

Tags: magento-1.7, reports, free-shipping

I started working with magento for a few weeks and I'm having a problem with free shipping. There is a way of retrieve the shipping price of the orders sold with promotions of free shipping?
I need to know how much I have to pay for the shipping company.

Answer (score 0):

No, this data is not saved. You would have to write a custom module that calculates the shipping price without promotion before placing the order (using an observer) and save that value to a new order attribute.

How to calculate the shipping price without promotion? That won't be easy. You will have to clone the quote, somehow disable the price rule calculation and collect the totals of the cloned quote.

I'll leave the details as an exercise for a more experienced developer, it is a bit out of scope for a StackExchange answer.